# serialize values without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building data for an ajax call. I am using jquery.

my function(simplified) is below.
I would like to use the jquery serialize() on vname and vemail, but it seems like you can only do this on form vars.  is there a way to do this with normal vars or do i need to do something else to make these vars safe for the ajax call?

Thanks

```
function sendEmailNotify(vname, vemail, docID){
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/servlet/trainingServlet",
           data: ({method: 'ajaxEmailNotify',vname: vname , vemail: vemail }),
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
               if ( data.success != "OK" ){
                   alert(data.message);
               }
           }
       });

   }
```

Comment: What are `vname` and `vemail`? Are they DOM elements or values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery `.serialize()` function can be called on a jQuery object that contains one or more forms, or a jQuery object that contains a specific set of individual form input elements, and will return a URL parameter string with all of those values.

If `vname` and `vemail` in your code refer to input elements, then you can create a jQuery object containing those, then call `.serialize()`. If, however, they are simply values, then you don't need to do anything else with them.

As a semi-related note, you don't need the parentheses around the object you're passing to the `data` property - I have no idea if having that will cause problems, but since they serve no purpose in being there you may as well remove them.